# Concatenate three dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate three dataframes but I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'tuple'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

I have checked and all three dataframes I want to concatenate are of type `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.

What's going wrong here..?

```
    indicators_df = pd.concat((SMA, MACD, mom),ignore_index=True, axis=1)
    indicators_df.columns = ['SMA', 'MACD', 'mom']
    indicators_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
indicators_df = pd.concat([SMA, MACD, mom],ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

should work if `SMA`,`MACD` and `mom` are datafraes